# How do I alter a linked list inside of a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap, adjacency-list

can you please advise me on how I can reach my list inside my map in order to alter it?

For example,

```
Map<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>>() list= new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>)();
```

how would I add a value specifically to the linkedlist? I'm trying to create a graph from a 2d array map, so I want iterate through every point which is the integer, and I want to add the neighbors to the linked list.

```
Maps<Integer(THIS IS THE SPOT, OR THE NODE), LinkedList<Integer>>(THIS IS THE NEIGHBORS OF THE SPOT/NODE).
```

Any ideas? I know there's something like

```
 list.get(list.values)
```

and I suppose it could work but I would have to get the values, adjust it, and then create a new Linked List so there's a lot of extra unnecessary steps, looking for a simpler way.

If my map looked like this

```
         1 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5
         2 -> 3 -> 7 -> 5
         3 -> 0 -> 2 -> 1
```

how would would I target the second node in the key 2, which is 7?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are getting bogged down with syntax.  Your `Map` uses `Integer` for its keys, and `LinkedList` for its values.  So let's create such a list and then put it into the map.

```
List<Integer> intList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
intList.add(1);
intList.add(2);

Map<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>>() listMap = new HashMap<Integer, LinkedList<Integer>)();
listMap.put(1, intList);
```

To access the list we put into the map, you can use the `get()` method along with the *key* for the entry you want (the key is `1` in this example):

```
List<Integer> someList = listMap.get(1);
```

Comment: It's honestly exactly what I'm struggling with haha, the syntax! And your example was very helpful, thanks! Just one more question, how would I GET values from a specific key? I'll update what I'm looking for in my question for clarification

Comment: To access the second linked list you would need to know the _key_ for that list.  Are you sure that you really want to use a map of lists, rather than a list of lists?

Comment: I was thinking about that too, but I didn't think it would be as efficient as a map and a map's O(1) look up time..but maybe implementing it that way would help me see things more clearly and it'd definitely be simpler! Haha thank you for advise